# android: how get the only contacts from device not google contacts or facebook contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I am doing a program that takes all contacts from phone and sim card. There is an option to get only contacts on phone and not Google contacts (or similar).

I tried with `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;`. This works but get all contacts also Google contact and Facebook contacts.

How do I do it?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?